# Declaring an instance of an object as 'global' within '__init__'

Tags: python

I'm maintaining an application written in Python, and came across something like this:

```
class A():

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        global a
        a = self

    ...
```

Can someone explain what's going on here on a detailed level and what the purpose of this of declaring the self as global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two lines

```
global a
a = self
```

make a global variable named `a` refer to whatever object is currently invoking its `__init__` method. Essentially, the application appears to be keeping track of the instance of `A` most recently instantiated. It should work something like this:

```
>>> o1 = A()
>>> a is o1    # o1 was most recently instantiated
True
>>> o2 = A()
>>> a is o1    # o1 is no longer the most recently instantiated ...
False
>>> a is o2    # ... o2 is
True
```